# Google App script on form submit trigger - delay

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script set up to send out an email on receiving data from a form into a spreadsheet.  However, the auto email generates from the spreadsheet, which takes a few seconds to update the fields - so if I use the onformsubmit trigger, the content of the auto email wrongly refers to the previous submission.

Is there a way to delay the auto email by a few seconds, giving the spreadsheet time to generate the right information before spitting out the email?

Any help appreciated!

Nick

Here is the code so far:

```
    function EmailFormConfirmation() { 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses");
      var email = sheet.getRange(2,9,1,1).getValue();  
      var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
         + "<P >Hi " 
         + sheet.getRange(4,9,1,1).getValue()
         + ","
         + "<P>You have received a new request, from <b>"
         + sheet.getRange(5,9,1,1).getValue()
         + "</b>.  "
         + sheet.getRange(8,9,1,1).getValue()
         + " asks:<i>"
         + "<br /><br />"
         + sheet.getRange(6,9,1,1).getValue()      
         + "</i><P>You can find your request on the log at number <b>"
         + sheet.getRange(10,9,1,1).getValue()
         + "</b>.  
         + "<br /><br />"
         + sheet.getRange(8,9,1,1).getValue()
         + "'s email address is:"
         + "<br /><br />"
         + sheet.getRange(9,9,1,1).getValue()   
         + "</HTML></BODY>";
        MailApp.sendEmail(email, "LMI Request", "", {htmlBody: message});   
    }
```

Comment: Show the current code you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function Utilities.sleep() to make the code wait so the spreadsheet has time to update. Here is the documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)

Answer (score 2):

When the form submission triggers your function, it passes an argument to that function. That argument contains an array with the values that the user submitted to the form.

Why not use that array? You don't have to wait on the spreadsheet updating, or risk sending a mixed up response.

I'm assuming you're only sending the data from the submitted form. If you're sending calculations based on previous submissions then this will not help you.

```
function EmailFormConfirmation(e) { 
    var email = e.values[1];

    var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
        + "<P >Hi " 
        + e.values[3]
        + ","
        + "<P>You have received a new request, from <b>"
        + e.values[4]
        + "</b>.  "
        + e.values[7]
        + " asks:<i>"
        + "<br /><br />"
        + e.values[5]    
        + "</i><P>You can find your request on the log at number <b>"
        + e.values[9]
        + "</b>.  
        + "<br /><br />"
        + e.values[7]
        + "'s email address is:"
        + "<br /><br />"
        + e.values[8]
        + "</HTML></BODY>";

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, "LMI Request", "", {htmlBody: message});   
}
```

Or something like that...

Comment: Thanks for your message.  The problem was that it wasn't just the form data, it was values derived from this data requiring some calculations.  So the sleep function above was the way to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar challenge whenever I creating the script linked to the form itself. When linking the script to the response spreadsheet instead, I do not encounter these issues.

Comment: Welcome SOP. Please use the comments section for making relevant comments. Thanks!