# How to Delay Google Form Response to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form that is linked to a spreadsheet. On the form side I added an onFormSubmit From form trigger.

The problem is that there are several other triggers that are fired on the spreadsheet side from onSubmit sending data to a webhook and then information is relayed to the last row of data.. (Triggers Zapier, webhook etc)

By the time all of the data is fully calculated and relayed back to the last row another submission from the form could come in during this process causing the functions to input the relayed data to last row from the form submission.

I need to delay the form responses for X amount of time to allow for data to finish calculating from the previous form submission.

I have tried using LockService and Utilities.sleep(20000), but it does not seem to prevent form submissions during the defined waitLock timeframe.

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
{
  try
  {
    var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
    // Wait for up to 30 seconds for other processes to finish.
    lock.waitLock(30000);
    Utilities.sleep(20000); // 20 second
    var formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
    var testInput = formResponses[0].getResponse();
    //append NEW FORM URL to MAIN SPREADSHEET
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jkvSWC1ew4mt1sEy6XX2vsc_5norWHrbOYQt5hLhwGA");
    var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();//gets the last row of entered data
    lastRow += 1;
    sh.getRange('D'+lastRow).setValue(testInput);
    // Release the lock so that other processes can continue.
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
  catch (error)
  {
// If there's an error, show the error message
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

Expected results: Delay a form response being added / submitted to the linked spreadsheet for X amount of time.

Actual results: Form receives a submission and the response is added to a new row on the sheet regardless of the lock being used. What is being delay is the additional information being added to the lastRow. But, what I'm looking for is to queue / delay submissions from the form.

Comment: `getPublicLock` was [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2014) in 2014. It says that "The old method names have been deprecated, but will continue to function", but personally, I'd feel happier if I was running the "official" code - which is, I think, `getScriptLock()`[ Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getScriptLock()).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did try getScriptLock() originally and it also didn’t solve the issue at hand. Forgot to swap it out when testing. You’re right it’s definitely better to use “official” up-to-date code.

Comment: Move `var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();` outside the "try" statement (as in this [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#waitLock(Integer)). Perhaps try add a Logger statement  to the catch to see what it is reporting.. Lastly, what is the purpose of setting a lock of 30 seconds, and then setting a sleep period of 20 seconds - kinds sounds counter intuitive?

Comment: This topic [Google App script on form submit trigger - delay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29544933/1330560) has a lot in common with your situation. The suggested/accepted answer didn't use the lock service, but simply uses the Sleep command.

Comment: As Tedinoz suggested, having both the lock and the sleep seems like overkill, and if you extend the wait too much you risk the case were another form is submitted. try with only the lock before the try (like Tedinoz suggested) and log both the end of the try and of the catch to see what is happening in the execution.

Comment: Why not try to control the specific timestamp of the event? That way, you can make sure the information added after the different triggers finish their tasks is linked to the right submission. Just a thought, but it might help with the issue you're facing. What others commentors think about this approach?